# when sending mail via a Intent we are getting bluetooth also in th echooser why?

Tags: android

when sending mails from intent we are calling  the intent using such as these `codestartActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send your email in:"))`, but we are getting Bluetooth also in the chooser, how to avoid Bluetooth from the chooser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
emailIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");
```

works for me! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "avoid Bluetooth from the chooser". If it says it supports your `Intent`, it will appear in the chooser. This is not significantly different than any other application that supports your `Intent`.

Either adjust your `Intent` to be more specific (e.g., did you specify a MIME type?) or roll your own "chooser" using `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`. How, precisely, you will filter out Bluetooth in a cross-device/cross-version manner, I have no idea.